# JavaScript Document is not defined, WebStorm IDE

Tags: javascript, webstorm, document

I started up learning some basic HTML, CSS and JS and reached the point where I should be able to connect them. But when I'm trying to access the document object it just says that the document is not defined

[image: app.js]

[image: index.html]

[image: error]

I've tried changing the IDE, done some research on the internet and I found that it might be NodeJS, since it's more server based and not browser based, but even so how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the html document directly in the browser and not run it via Webstorm, cause Webstrom thinks you are writing node and in node document is not defined.

Here's a link to the JetBrains Docs for information on how to debug vanilla js code: [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-javascript-in-chrome.html#debugging_js_on_built_in_server_example)

Comment: By that you just mean to have the index.html opened in a browser tab, if this is the case it still shows the error. If not, is there a special configuration to open the html document into the browser ?

Comment: yep there's special configuration look at the docs link I sent you

Comment: and for the curiosity, how can the same problem be fixed in visual studio ?

Comment: If you are talking about Visual Studio Code, then I didn't know that such a problem existed. If you mean actual Visual Studio then I can't help you because I don't use it.

Comment: I was referring to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If we are going over to a different question it's best to mark the answer as accepted and then create a new question for this problem with vscode.